# Why the answer of following code is 1000?

Tags: c, pointers

I came across a question on pointer which is given below. I am not able to understand why the output of the code below is 1000 and not 10. Can anyone help me how it is possible?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int y;
void main()
{
    int x, *px, **ppx;
    x = 10;
    y = 1000;
    px = &x;
    ppx = &px;
    f3(ppx);
    printf("%d", *px);
}
void f3(int **pp)
{
    *pp = &y;
}
```

Comment: The function is changing the value of `px` from `&x` to `&y`, and `y` has the value `1000`.

Comment: That's not valid C. Any modern compiler will complian for a missing declaration. Also `main` has to be `int main(void)` at minimum

Comment: @Yatendra Dubey Does the code compile?

Comment: Does the compiler not warn you when you try to pass `ppx` to `f3` where the forward declaration is missing?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes the code does compile

Answer (score 5):

This statement:

```
px = &x;
```

assigns the address of `x` to `px`. This statement:

```
ppx = &px;
```

assigns the address of `px` to `ppx`. This statement:

```
f3(ppx);
```

passes the value of `ppx` to `f3`. In `f3`, this statement:

```
*pp = &y;
```

assigns the address of `y` to the place that `pp` points. `pp` is the parameter of `f3`, which was given the value `ppx` in the call.

That is, `pp` is `ppx`, which points to `px`. Since `pp` points to `px`, `*pp = &y` puts the address of `y` in `px`.

Now `px` points to `y`. Then this statement:

```
printf("%d", *px);
```

prints the thing that `px` points to, which is `y`, which is 1000.

Answer (score 0):

This statement `*pp = &y;` causes to print `1000`. Before calling `f3()`  `px` points to address of `x` as `px=&x;` but in `f3()`  `px` got modified as address of `y`.

```
int y;
void f3(int **pp){ /*since you didn't declare functin,
                   so either declare it or define before main() */
        *pp = &y;/* px contains now address of y */
}
int main(){ /* use int main() instead of void main() */
        int x,*px,**ppx;
        x=10;
        y=1000;
        px=&x;/* px points to address of x*/
        ppx=&px; /* ppx points to address of px */
        f3(ppx); /* passing ppx i.e address of px 
                 And in f3() *pp = &y means px got replaced by 
                 address of y */
        printf("%d",*px); /* prints value at address of y, not address of x */
        return 0;
}
```

Compile your code always with `-Wall` flag, don't ignore warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can change an object in a function passing it by reference that is indirectly through a pointer.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int *p, int value )
{
    *p = value;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;

    printf( "Before call f x = %d\n", x );

    int *px = &x;

    f( px, 20 );

    printf( "After call f x = %d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Before call f x = 10
After call f x = 20
```

In the program the function deals with a pointer to the variable `x` declared in main. That is the pointer points to the variable `x`. Dereferencing the pointer you get access to the variable and thus can change it.

```
*p = 20;
```

The same way you can change an object that has a pointer type. To do this you have to pass the object/pointer by reference as it was shown above.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int * T;

void f( T *pp, T p )
{
    *pp = p;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;

    T px = NULL;

    T *ppx = &px;

    f( ppx, &x );

    printf( "After call f *px = %d\n", *px );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
After call f *px = 10
```

At the beginning of the program the pointer `px` that has the type `int *` (due to the typedef) is initialized by `NULL`. Then it is passed to the function `f` by reference

```
T *ppx = &px;

f( ppx, &x );
```

that is indirrectly through a pointer to the pointer `px`. Within the function the pointer `px` is reassigned with the address of the variable `x`by dereferencing the pointer `pp` that points to the original pointer `px`.